Growth rate of the sequence $a_{n} = n\sqrt{a_{n-1}}.$
Let $a_1=1;\ a_{n} = n\sqrt{a_{n-1}}\ \forall\ n\geq 2.$
Then it seems that, based on computation with a calculator - up to $n=50$ - that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(a_n - ( n^2-2n-1 )\right) = 0.$

Is this really the case, and if so, why?


Perhaps one can prove via induction something like $$\left| a_n - ( n^2-2n-1 ) \right| < \frac C n$$

Note that @Euclid's inequality does not have to hold for all $n$: it would suffice for it to be true for all $n\geq N$ for some positive $N$.

I tried and found out that the upper-half $a_n < ( n^2-2n-1 ) + \dfrac C n$ follows by induction, but the lower-half $a_n > ( n^2-2n-1 ) - \dfrac C n$ does not.

A non-recursive formula for $a_n$ is $\prod\limits_{k=2}^{n}k^{2^{k-n}}$, if that helps.

@Euclid Seems like $C$ is around $4$.

I actually got $a_n \sim C \sqrt[3]n$

$$\log a_n=2(1-1/2^n)\log n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\log(1-k/n)}{2^k}.$$
Break the sum into $[0,M\log n]$ and $[M\log n,n]$ for $M \gg 1$. The error
in second term is $O(n^{1-M+\epsilon})$.
Expand $\log(1-k/n)$ as a series, replace the sum $[0,M \log n]$ by $[0,\infty)$, again the error
is $O(n^{1-M+\epsilon})$.
Thus one gets the asymptotic expansion
$$\log a_n=2 \log n-\frac{2}{n}-\frac{3}{n^2} -\frac{26}{3 n^3}-\frac{75}{2 n^4}-\frac{1082}{5 n^5}-\ldots$$
or equivalently the asymptotic expansion
$$a_n \sim n^2-2n-1-\frac{4}{n}-\frac{21}{n^2}-\frac{138}{n^3}-\frac{1091}{n^4}-\ldots $$

@user297024: that looks like a complete answer to me!

Note that $a_{29}\ge29^2-2\times29-1-\frac5{29}$
Suppose $n\ge29$ and $a_n\ge n^2-2n-1-\frac5n$.
Then $a_{n+1}=(n+1)\sqrt{a_n}\ge(n+1)\sqrt{n^2-2n-1-\frac5n}$
\begin{align}&(a_{n+1})^2\\
\ge&(n+1)^2\left(n^2-2n-1-\frac5n\right)\\
=&\frac{n^5-4n^3-9n^2-11n-5}n\\
=&\left((n+1)^2-2(n+1)-1-\frac5{n+1}\right)^2+\frac{n^4-23n^3-64n^2-70n-5}{n^3+2n^2+n}\\
>&\left((n+1)^2-2(n+1)-1-\frac5{n+1}\right)^2\end{align}
So $a_{n+1}\ge(n+1)^2-2(n+1)-1-\frac5{n+1}$ for all $n\ge29$.
Note that $a_6\le6^2-2\times6-1$.
Suppose $n\ge6$ and $a_n\le n^2-2n-1$.
Then $a_{n+1}=(n+1)\sqrt{a_n}\le(n+1)\sqrt{n^2-2n-1}$.
\begin{align}&(a_{n+1})^2\\
\le&(n+1)^2(n^2-2n-1)\\
=&n^4-4n^2-4n-1\\
=&\left((n+1)^2-2(n+1)-1\right)^2-4n-5\\
<&\left((n+1)^2-2(n+1)-1\right)^2\end{align}
So $a_{n+1}\le(n+1)^2-2(n+1)-1$ for all $n\ge6$.

Nice solution! How were you able to come up with such a strategy of proof?

I just looked at the error term.
